# d3 - Append elements to external SVG file

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a graphic I'd like to load as a background to my d3 visualization (or simply as an `svg` that I can append `circle` elements to).  The illustration is in `svg` format.  I have tried to load it into my `html` file in such a way that would allow me to then append elements (such as circles) to the (or on top of) the `svg` file or to the `div` that it is in.  Here are two approaches I have tried:

```
<script>

d3.xml("bal.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
});

var circle = svg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", 100)
                .attr("cy", 100)
                .attr("r", 20)
                .style("fill", "red");

</script>
```

The svg image appears perfectly fine, but no circle shows up. In Firefox, the `html` for the external `svg` file shows up as:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" 
width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
enable-background="new 0 0 250 250" xml:space="preserve">
```

I have also tried:

```
<div id="htmlEmbed"></div>

<script>

d3.select("#htmlEmbed")
.append("object")
.attr("data", "tba2.svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500)
.attr("type", "image/svg");

d3.select("#htmlEmbed")
.append("circle")
.attr("cx", 600)
.attr("cy", 600)
.attr("r", 20)
.style("fill", "red");
```

Again, the svg image appears perfectly fine, but no circle shows up.  In this case, the html shows in the browser as:

```
<object width="500" height="500" data="tba2.svg" type="image/svg">
#document
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" 
width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
enable-background="new 0 0 250 250" xml:space="preserve"> … </svg>
</object>
```

I have the feeling this should be rather straightforward to do, but I don't know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your first example, you didn't tell us how `svg` is defined. Note that you may need to add the svg namespace to any elements you append (i.e. `.append("svg:circle")`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the first example, I did not explicitly define svg. My assumption was that by doing svg.append("circle"), the code would select the svg element of the image (that appears in the html due to the preceding line). How can I tell it to use the svg of the image?  Incidentally, if I open the svg file in a text editor and simply add the <circle> markup with cx, cy attributes and open it in a browser, the circles appear perfectly fine.  There must a way to have d3 append these elements, but I don't know how to get it to recognize the svg of the image.

Comment: D3 won't magically assign variables based on what's on the page. Instead of `svg`, try something like `d3.select("svg")`.

Comment: I just tried d3.select("svg").append("circle") instead and it did not work. No circle element appears in the html.

Comment: Have you verified that the `svg` element is selected correctly? It would help if you could provide a complete working example.

Comment: I just set up a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Jw2f8/5/ .  The svg image that is linked is not the one I want to use, but I did not know how to add a local svg file.  I put both methods in, but commented one out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There were two issues with the code you've tried. First, you need to define `svg` properly and second, you need to execute the code that modifies the SVG after it's been loaded. Because of the asynchronous nature of `d3.xml`, this was not the case.

So the code you need to run is this.

```
d3.xml("http://openvz.org/images/1/17/Warning.svg", function(xml) {
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);

  var circle = d3.select("svg").append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 100)
            .attr("cy", 100)
            .attr("r", 20)
            .style("fill", "red");
});
```

Working fiddle (modulo security restrictions) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jw2f8/8/).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for figuring this out! If there is a Genius badge on stackoverflow, you should have it!

Comment: Is there any way to load the external SVG as normal objects that can be selected and manipulated outside of the ```d3.xml``` function?

Comment: That is the case already, the problem is, as I've said, that `d3.xml` is asynchronous. After it has finished loading, you can do whatever you want to the SVG.